Split multiple floor-plan presented in an image using python
I am trying to split floor plans drawn in an image. The input image (Grayscale) consists of multiple floor plans, separated by blank space. Output will be the segmented floor plans.
I am using a Window which iterates through top to bottom of the image. Entropy calculation is being performed and appending the Window when entropy crosses a certain threshold. Problem is I cannot use this method with respect to other images. Due to the threshold mechanism, floor plans are not properly separated. Following is the code that I am experimenting with:
window = 30
stary_y = 0
end_y = 0 + window
img = img[start_height:end_height,:]#.copy()
iteration = int(img.shape[0] / window)
i = 0
is_stack = False
start = 0
end = 0
base = numpy.zeros((1, img.shape[1]), dtype = img.dtype)
c = []
while i < iteration:
    prob = numpy.histogram(img[stary_y:end_y, :], bins = 256, range = (0, 256), density = True)[0]
    ent = scipy.stats.entropy(prob, base = 2)
    if ent > 0.25:
        if is_stack == False:
            start = i * window
            is_stack = True
        base = numpy.concatenate([base, img[stary_y:end_y, :]])
        c.append([i, is_stack])
    else:
        is_stack = False
        if is_stack == False and base.shape[0] > 32:
            end = window * i
            c.append([i, is_stack])
            c = []
            start, end = 0, 0
            plt.imshow(base, cmap = "gray")
            plt.show()
            base = numpy.zeros((1, img.shape[1]), dtype = img.dtype)
        else:
            c = []
            start, end = 0, 0
            base = numpy.zeros((1, img.shape[1]), dtype = img.dtype)

    stary_y, end_y = stary_y + window, end_y + window
    i += 1

Image  is the input and it should output . The concept I have applied, is producing the segments . Seg 4 is containing 2 floor plans which is unexpected, it should be broken into 2 images. Seg 2 and 6 are not floor plans. I understand that these problems are due to window size and threshold. What approach should I take to generate properly separate floor plans?

that is a complex task without an obvious solution. as such, it's way too broad for SO. one issue is the huge number spread across multiple "pages".
